# Force SSL in .htaccess or in my PHP code, results in redirect loop error

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to force the use of HTTPS, I am hopeful to accomplish this with the .htaccess file, but have also attempted to use code. I am using Zend framework, and have tried to use this code in the `Bootstrap.php` in attempt in avoiding a conflicting rule or some erroneous setting on the HTTP server.

```
public function _initForceSSL() {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
        if(!headers_sent()) {
            header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header(sprintf(
                'Location: https://%s%s',
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
            ));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the same results as if I where to do this...

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.tld/$1 [R,L]
```

in my .htaccess file. I get the same redirect loop complaint on my local dev. server (where I have full access to all settings, regular 'ol LAMP stack it is). Also, same results on Zend's PHPCloud (using Zend server).

Here is my full .htacces file, I've tried using the rules in various places...

```
    setEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

    #setEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
    #setEnv APPLICATION_ENV testing

    RewriteEngine On 

#tried it here

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#tried here
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

#tried it here too...
```

I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've attempted a few other 'popular' method for a rewrite as well. Also, btw I do use my actual domain name in the RewriteRule.

My only requirement is that the entire application NOT be available over a non secure connection (SSL Only).

Comment: So you have a .htaccess that would redirect to user to https:// and then Zend is making them return to http://, that's my guess. Is there anything else in the .htacces or php that would cause it to redirect to http:// (maybe a domain setting in zend?)

Comment: Good question, I'll have to investigate that possibility. Thanks for the suggestion, it makes me look at it a little different :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the vhost file, you can do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  example.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I won't always have access to the vhost settings for this application...I don't even have access to it on the dev cloud I'm using, only my own workstation, so I'll be forced to do this in the .htaccess and/or in my code. Thanks though!